# SSRS Avg function returns result that is different than expected

Tags: function, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, average, iif-function

Currently I am trying to average a set of numbers, but with certain conditions.

Is it possible to use an `iif()` within an `avg()` and return the correct result?

Furthermore, as of now my computations return a decimal returned to a power (8.9267....E -05).

I tried circumventing the `AVG` function by conditionally summing and then dividing by a conditional count but it gives me the same results.

Can someone explain why this is returned and offer help?

Currently I have:

```
=avg(iif((This_case) AND (That_case) AND (This_conditional)
  , Fields!ResponseRate.Value
  , 0))
```

Essentially I want the average ResponseRate if certain conditions are met.

The `sum` function works fine for the conditions but the average doesn't.

Comment: You can definitely use `IIf` within `Avg` and get the correct results. Without your data it's impossible to say what's happening in your particular case. Are you able to supply a dataset of a few rows that demonstrate your issue in a repeatable test case?

Comment: @IanPreston That's what I thought, but I'm getting the results I mentioned. Currently I have =avg(iif((This_case) AND (That_case) AND (This_conditional), Fields!ResponseRate.Value, 0)) Essentially I want the average ResponseRate if certain conditions are met. (I'm relatively new to SSRS by the way so I may misunderstand you). The sum function works fine for the conditions but the average doesn't.

Comment: Do you want to exclude the `False` values from the calculation entirely? As above you're still including them, just setting them to `0` and hence still including them in the calculation. This might explain your unexpected results. If you want to exclude them entirely use `Nothing` instead of `0`. As above, this is still just supposition - can you replicate your issue with a sample dataset and add this to the question?

Comment: Using Nothing instead of 0 worked. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! I added an answer based on our discussion; please consider setting this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can definitely use `IIf` within `Avg` and get the correct results.

Do you want to exclude the `False` values from the calculation entirely?

In your example you're still including them, just setting them to `0` and hence still including them in the calculation. This might explain your unexpected results.

If you want to exclude them entirely use `Nothing` instead of `0`.

**Edit after comment**

You can nest an expression in *another* `IIf` statement and check for NULL values using `IsNothing`.

Say your condition average expression is:

```
=Avg(IIf(Fields!ID.Value > 5, Fields!value.Value, Nothing))
```

You can return 0 for NULL values with something like:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Avg(IIf(Fields!ID.Value > 5, Fields!value.Value, Nothing)))
    , 0.0
    , Avg(IIf(Fields!ID.Value > 5, Fields!value.Value, Nothing)))
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question-if it tries to average 0 items, it doesn't return a number. This poses a problem as I want my report to be flexible (where most cases it will average a number, but sometimes there are 0 instances). Would a conversion function fix this problem?

Comment: You can add an extra check to handle these cases by wrapping the `avg` expression in an `IIf` expression and checking for your edge case; see above for an example.

Comment: People like you are why I love this site. You've been extremely helpful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add my two cents to this one, a little late, but also valuable.  I was able to use the above code to Average out a data set if another record appears X number of times.

```
=AVG(IIF(Count(Fields!AcctNo.Value, "AcctNo1") = 2, Fields!Limit.Value, Nothing))
```

So, if the acctno field appears 1 time, avg the limit field for that row group.  Ian's example was very helpful